# How to graph audio frequency on a reactjs voice recorder with html/css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to achieve something like this https://online-voice-recorder.com/ using pure html and css.

I'm using reactjs and in our application and there is a component with a voice recorder. I have achieved to record, preview(play) and successfully upload to the server using html5 native recording API. The audio file is currently being recorded and stored as a File JS object in the state of the component and encoded as mp3 when the user stops recording to send it to the server.

Here's how I record and store the audio.

```
navigator.getUserMedia(
    { audio: true },
    stream => {
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        this.mediaRecorder.start();
        this.pulseInterval = setInterval(() => {
            let newDuration = this.state.duration;
            this.setState({ recording: true, showPulse: !this.state.showPulse, duration: ++newDuration, compatibilityError: false });
        }, 1000);
        this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', e => this.audioDataChunks.push(e.data));
        this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
            this.audioBlob = new Blob(this.audioDataChunks, { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
            const audioBlobToFile = new File([this.audioBlob], this.state.audioName, { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
            this.setState({
                audioFile: audioBlobToFile,
                audioDataChunks: this.audioDataChunks
            });
        });
    }
)
```

I have looked into some js libraries and npm packages but they are mostly predefined components or very robust API's with a ton of functionalities and all i want is to visualize the voice of the user while recording. Also our designers have an expected look and none of the options I've seen seem to be easy to style.

I would hope someone could tell me about the easiest way to achieve it.

Comment: You mean like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API ?

Comment: yes!, I'll look into it, that seems very promising.